# Ruby system exit status constants

Tags: ruby

The Ruby [`Kernel#exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) takes a status code argument. This code corresponds to the `exit(3)` C function call, for which C libraries provide predefined constants. Using constants is more readable than using literal integers. The macOS `exit(3)` man page says:

```
The C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (``ISO C99'')) defines the values 0,
EXIT_SUCCESS, and EXIT_FAILURE as possible values of status.  Cooperating
processes may use other values; in a program which might be called by a
mail transfer agent, the values described in sysexits(3) may be used to
provide more information to the parent process.
```

Does Ruby provide constants that correspond to the status codes such as `EXIT_SUCCESS` quoted above? Preferably in the language itself, standard library or if nothing else then as a Ruby Gem.

Comment: `exit(true)` (or just `exit`) corresponds to `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `exit(false)` corresponds to `EXIT_FAILURE`

Comment: Stefan: Great, this already goes a long way. Please consider posting this as an answer so that it can be upvoted and be a candidate for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation for [`Kernel#exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit):

> `true` and `FALSE` of *status* means success and failure respectively.

More specifically:

- `exit(true)` (or just `exit`) corresponds to `EXIT_SUCCESS`
- `exit(false)` corresponds to `EXIT_FAILURE`

The underlying [C code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_1/process.c#L3726-L3747):

```c
switch (status) {
  case Qtrue:
    istatus = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    break;
  case Qfalse:
    istatus = EXIT_FAILURE;
    break;
  // ...
}
```

Other values are system dependent and therefore don't have a constant in the C standard.